# MySQL - Left Outer Join not updating original table

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a toy dataset where I am trying to count the number of posts for each user. I seem to be getting the correct count values but the count column in the users table is not updated with the values.

I'm new to mysql and very confused! Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 users:
 +---------+------+-------+
| user_id | user | pword |
+---------+------+-------+
|       1 | Amy  | abcd  |
|       2 | Jess | efgh  |
|       3 | Lori | ijkl  |
+---------+------+-------+

posts:
+---------+-------------+------+
| post_id | post        | user |
+---------+-------------+------+
|       1 | hi          | Lori |
|       2 | hello       | Jess |
|       3 | hello again | Jess |
|       4 | and again   | Jess |
+---------+-------------+------+

mysql> ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN post_count INT;
mysql> SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(p.user) AS post_count FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user LIKE p.user GROUP BY u.user_id;
+---------+------------+
| user_id | post_count |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          0 |
|       2 |          3 |
|       3 |          1 |
+---------+------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+---------+------+-------+------------+
| user_id | user | pword | post_count |
+---------+------+-------+------------+
|       1 | Amy  | abcd  |       NULL |
|       2 | Jess | efgh  |       NULL |
|       3 | Lori | ijkl  |       NULL |
+---------+------+-------+------------+
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to use an update statement to update the table. Post your update query.

Comment: You have to have an update query to update the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
UPDATE users
JOIN ( SELECT u.user_id AS user_id,
              COUNT( p.user ) AS post_count
       FROM users u
       LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user LIKE p.user
       GROUP BY u.user_id ) postCountFinder
    ON users.user_id = postCountFinder.user_id
SET users.post_count = postCountFinder.post_count;
```

This question takes your list of users and post counts obtained from the following...

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       COUNT( p.user ) AS post_count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user LIKE p.user
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

... and performs an `INNER JOIN` with `Users` on shared value of `user_id`, creating a dataset with every row from `users` having the corresponding count tacked on the end.

We then use the `SET` command to set the empty `post_count` from `users` to its corresponding joined count.

If you have any questions or comments, thenplease feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Yay!! Thank you!! This worked like a charm :-). Thanks for the nice explanation too.

Comment: You're welcome - glad to be of help.  Please note, if an Answer answers your Question to your satisfaction and is preferred over the other Answers to your question, you can accept it as the Answer by clicking on the tick next to the top of the Answer.  This gives the answerer a small reward of 15 points and removes the Question from the list of StackOverflow's unanswered Questions.

Comment: Will do! I accepted your response as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need update statement to update the value in the newly added column.Try this:

```
Update usr
set usr.post_count=tbl.post_count
from users usr
inner join
(select  u.user_id,COUNT(p.user) 
AS post_count FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user LIKE p.user GROUP BY u.user_id ) tbl
on tbl.user_id=usr.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I'm getting a syntax error? Not sure why?